# Wordpress show posts that start today and end in one year

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know some way to do this, maybe someone can help me out a little bit!
This is the code i have at the moment:

```
<?php $featured = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=23'); while($featured ->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();  ?>
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');  $image_url = $image_url[0]; ?>
<?php $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url'); $image_url = str_replace($blogurl, '', $image_url); ?>
```

So straight forward question is how can i display posts that start today and end in one year, from a specific category
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Time Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) section in the WordPress Codex page for `WP Query`, the part about filters should prove useful. Alternatively, see this [post on how to hide content based on age of post in WordPress](http://robmalon.com/display-hide-content-date-age-posts-wordpress-hack/).